# Use primary site contact form 7 post type across WordPress multisites

Tags: php, wordpress, oop, hook, contact-form-7

I am currently using the Contact Form 7 plugin on a Worpdress Multisite.

My goal is to use only the primary site contact form 7 post from the main site wp_post table across all sites.

Basically to just have the primary site contact form 7 running on all sites including shortcodes and admin menu page without alternating the plugin files.

My idea was to overwrite the plugin instance in the functions.php file with a *add_action* hook.

Here is the plugin constructor

```php
private function __construct( $post = null ) {

  $post = get_post( $post );

  if ( $post and self::post_type == get_post_type( $post ) ) {

    $this->id = $post->ID;
    $this->name = $post->post_name;
    $this->title = $post->post_title;
    $this->locale = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_locale', true );

    $properties = $this->get_properties();

   foreach ( $properties as $key => $value ) {
    if ( metadata_exists( 'post', $post->ID, '_' . $key ) ) {
         $properties[$key] = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_' . $key, true );
    } elseif ( metadata_exists( 'post', $post->ID, $key ) ) {
           $properties[$key] = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $key, true );
    }
   }

    $this->properties = $properties;
    $this->upgrade();


    }
     do_action( 'wpcf7_contact_form', $this );
}
```

Example function on how to overwrite

```php
// define the wpcf7_contact_form callback 
function action_wpcf7_contact_form( $instance ) { 
    // make action magic happen here... 
}; 

// add the action 
add_action( 'wpcf7_contact_form', 'action_wpcf7_contact_form', 10, 1 );
```

However, the class gets instantiated before I can overwrite it. Also since the constructor class is private I don't think there is a way to change it ?

A different approach I had in mind was to use the *pre_get_posts* to change the post type to the primary blog one. I can't seem to find any good examples.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I have understood your question exactly, You should definitely consider using  [`mu-plugins`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins).

The plugins in that folder will be automatically activated for all your network sites. They can not be deactivated.

In the case of CF7, you probably will have to use both your custom plugin and the original CF7 as `MU` - and maybe rethink the structure of your custom plugin ( for example, where is the Custom post type defined ) , but it is definitely a strategy that I have used in many occasions before for similar scenarios.

Another approach would be to add a custom CF7 shortcode ( note - not a regular wp shortcode ) and insert it in any post or -

use some other cf7 hooks like `wpcf7_posted_data` or `wpcf7_before_send_mail` to do whatever you want with the form.

all of the above, even if different approached than what you had in mind, should work. Like in my comment - I am not sure why you are hooked on accessing the specific post table for each post ( unless - again - I misunderstood what you are trying to achieve - a property listing site ? ).

Comment: Sorry that my question was confusing to you.

The contact form plugin is enabled as mu-plugin and every new wp install has the plugin and is using the post type from their own wp_post table. Like wp_post_2, wp_post_3 etc.

I want any new site to use only the main site wp_post table for this particular plugin to retrieve the data instead of their own instance table.

Essentially I will have a lot of sites running on one multisite and if I want to change a form I simply just change it at one place instead of replacing every form for all sites.

Comment: like I said, if your custom plugin is in `mu-plugins` and is constructed correctly than also all of the sites will have the same `post type` - unless you are talking about the posts themselves ( and not the type ). have you tried to define the post-type in the custom plugin also ? again - if I understand correctly  there is no need to access the db tables directly ..

Comment: Yeah, the contact form 7 shortcode which is showing the forms on the frontend is retrieving the data (post & post meta) from the wp_post table. Therefore I'll need some sort of workaround.

If I would modify the contact form 7 plugin directly with switch_to_blog(); and restore_current_blog(); it would work but I don't want to change the plugin file since it will give me troubles updating the plugin later on.

Comment: private function __construct( $post = null ) {

switch_to_blog(1); 

  $post = get_post( $post );

  do_the_stuff();
    }
     restore_current_blog();
     do_action( 'wpcf7_contact_form', $this );
}

Comment: of course you do not need to change the plugin - but create your custom plugin to hook on the many entry points that CF7 has. this is exactly what makes it an amazing plugin, even if documentation might not be always easy to find. try [here](http://hookr.io/plugins/contact-form-7/4.7/hooks/#index=a)

Comment: That's were I found this hook add_action( 'wpcf7_contact_form', 'action_wpcf7_contact_form', 10, 1 );  Which I was referring to in my question.

wpcf7_contact_form is used in the constructor for the post object. I've tried using that hook and setting the $instance to null but nothing seems to work, since the instance has already been instantiated. Not sure what I am doing wrong...

Comment: maybe it is hooking too soon because of the execution order ->mu-plugins->alphabetic->normal-plugins.. did you try another simple function on the same hook ?